# Native/CLI C++: How can I convert from vector<class1_native> to List<class1_cli>

Tags: c++, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I'm writing a Native/CLI DLL in C++. I'll eventually call the DLL from C# code (which I'm much more familiar with), but I'm trying to wrap my Native C++ classes with a CLI wrapper.

So my question is, what's the best way for me to convert an std::vector to a List class?

The classes are mostly simple, the most complex looks like this:

```
class SecurityPrincipal
{
public:
    wstring distinguishedName;
    SECURITYPRINCIPAL_NODE_TYPE NodeType;
    vector<LDAPAttribute> Attributes;
    vector<SecurityPrincipal> Nodes;
}
```

To be honest, I haven't even been able to get a `vector<wstring>` into a `List<String>`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard algorithm/function included with C++ that allows that level of transformation. But is there any reason a `for` loop won't work? The following is brain-compiled.

```
typedef System::Collections::Generic::List<class1_cli> MyList;
typedef std::vector<class1_native> MyVector;

MyList^ NativeToManaged(MyVector& v) {
    MyList^ result = gcnew MyList();
    if (result != nullptr) {
        for (MyVector::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
            class1_native& nativeValue = *i;
            result.Add(gcnew class1_cli(nativeValue));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried for a few hours to get this to compile/run, but couldn't. I'm having trouble with this line: gcnew class1_cli(nativeValue). Are you saying I should put in a constructor to initialize the CLI class with native data, or is there something here I'm not getting? I tried to convert with (SecurityPrincipal_CLI^)nativeValue, but that wouldn't work either.

Comment: Well, I assume your CLI class somehow wraps the native type, doesn't it? Exactly how is up to your implementation.

Comment: Ok cool. I was hoping there was an easier way, but I suppose there isn't. Ahh well. +1 for the detailed answer.